# how to call a function multiple times with where clause in php pdo?

Tags: php, function, pdo, while-loop, where-clause

I am new to php and trying hard to learn its why you guys and gals need to Forgive me for asking a lot!

Here is my question;

I am trying to call a function with where clause multiple times, I have read allmost all posts and examples still didn't understand how to do it.

I tought that An example will be more useful than any blurb I can write.

Here is the function I am trying to create and use it multiple times :

```
function getTable($tableName, $clause) {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$tableName." WHERE ".$clause." = :".$clause);
        $stmt->bindParam(":$clause", $clause, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    return $stmt;
}
```

I am not sure if my fucntion is safe or its rigth.

AND this is how I am trying to call function, which I dont know how to call table name and where clause and how to turn while loop.

```
getTable('posts');
```

If you give an example of creating and caling function, I would be grateful, Thanks

Comment: Why don't you go for some ORM in php?

Comment: tought pdo is beter, guys here offered pdo and I got to learn first .lol

Comment: What is this function's purpose? Why it is called getTable? What are real life usage examples?

Comment: as I write in question, I am trying to create a function that I can use with multiple table and where caluse instead of creating a function each time, function name is an example **getTable** and I dont think its meter what you call to a function. since its works fine.

Comment: Well your function is not safe. And you cannot use a while statement with it. You need another function that accepts arbitrary SQL and an array of parameters.

Comment: Yep that is why I asked if my function is safe or created right way, my function is an example, I wanted if anyone can give me a correct example. Thank @Your Common Sense

Comment: Check the duplicated thread to do it dynamically. But as I understand your code, you dont even want to use the where clause, is this correct? Can you maybe show us some example SQL-Queries you want to accomplish with this function?

Comment: `function runQuery($sql, $parameters = []) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($parameters);
    return $stmt;
}` I want to use it dynamicly But dont know how to call it and lis rows @Kingalione

Comment: No I mean your SQL Queries. How will they look like? Do you need them to have ORDER BY and LIMIT functionalities. Can the WHERE clause contain SUB-SELECTS and stuff like that. Or is it just a basic WHERE clause without complex stuff. Please edit your initial post with some example SQL-Queries.

Comment: What do you mean, "dynamically"? Did you check examples section? to get all rows you simply have to tell it to get all rows, `$rows = runQuery($pdo, $sql, $parameters)->fetchAll();`. See how to do it with a function: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper#function

Comment: yes I did and updated my function too didnt work for me, in your example how will I give parameters ? `$rows = runQuery($pdo, $sql, $parameters)->fetchAll();` I tried examples in https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper#function

Comment: I call function like : `$rows = $pdo->runQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username > ?", [$username])->fetchAll();` but having error : Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::runQuery() in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, your function is not safe. Moreover it is just useless.  There is no use case where you would use it like this `getTable('posts');`. And for the everything else it is much better to allow the full SQL syntax, not some limited subset.

The simplest yet most powerful PDO function I can think of is a function that accepts a PDO object, an SQL query, and array with input variables. A PDO statement is returned. I wrote about such function in my article about [PDO helper functions](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper#function). So here is the code:

```
function pdo($pdo, $sql, $args = NULL)
{
    if (!$args)
    {
         return $pdo->query($sql);
    }
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($args);
    return $stmt;
}
```

With this function you will be able to run any query, with any number of WHERE conditions, and get results in many different formats. Here are some examples from the article mentioned above:

```
// getting the number of rows in the table
$count = pdo($pdo, "SELECT count(*) FROM users")->fetchColumn();

// the user data based on email
$user = pdo($pdo, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?", [$email])->fetch();

// getting many rows from the table
$data = pdo($pdo, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE salary > ?", [$salary])->fetchAll();

// getting the number of affected rows from DELETE/UPDATE/INSERT
$deleted = pdo($pdo, "DELETE FROM users WHERE id=?", [$id])->rowCount();

// insert
pdo($pdo, "INSERT INTO users VALUES (null, ?,?,?)", [$name, $email, $password]);

// named placeholders are also welcome though I find them a bit too verbose
pdo($pdo, "UPDATE users SET name=:name WHERE id=:id", ['id'=>$id, 'name'=>$name]);

// using a sophisticated fetch mode, indexing the returned array by id
$indexed = pdo($pdo, "SELECT id, name FROM users")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

Special for you, here is the `while` example, though this method is considered clumsy and outdated:

```
$stmt = pdo($pdo,"SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE field = ?",[$value]);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

Comment: Having error  **PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in function line 116**  which is `$stmt->execute($args);`  This is how I changed my code  `$stmt = pdo($pdo,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?",$_SESSION['username']);
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
     echo $row['username'];
    }` and session is not empty

Comment: you need to provide an array for this parameter. if you have a string, put it in brackets, as shown in the examples,  `[$_SESSION['username']]`

Comment: And you don't need while for this. `$row = pdo($pdo,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", [$_SESSION['username']])->fetch();`

Comment: wow :):) thanks, thanks  it works with brackets you made my day :) thank you very much.

Comment: I need a while loop or foreach loop to return all rows like 1, 2, 3, if there is another way to do show me please :)

Comment: @dilekkoç you are selecting only one user, there is no way to show many rows. For another query, that returns many rows, just use while or foreach

Comment: I know that :) but I cant swith to `$row = pdo($pdo,"SELECT * FROM users)->fetch();` without WHERE clause and show multpile rows :) thanks again for your help.

Comment: @dilekkoç but you could do `$stmt = pdo($pdo,"SELECT * FROM users);` and then use while of foreach.

Comment: not much difference between a normal query and function than just saving you writing 3 lines of codes :)

Comment: Was this answer posted before the edit? Why was the edit made @dilek ? I feel like the edit should be rolled back.

Comment: nope, its sent after my edit, edit and made because of corrected function