# How to count and auto create bindParams in pdo?

Tags: php, function, pdo

I am trying to create a function to auto create bindParams on function from [Your Common Sence](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense)

Here [PDO helper functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58856805/how-to-call-a-function-multiple-times-with-where-clause-in-php-pdo).

**NOTICE :** I know how to use function with executition, I am trying to use binds in it.

Here is the function how I am trying, This function calling to another function which counts and creates bindParams :

```
function insert($sql, $param_types, $args) {
    $stmt= $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $this->CreateParams($sql, $param_types, $args);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Here is the second function which will count and bind values :

```
function CreateParams($sql, $param_types $args) {
    $param_references[] = & $param_types;
    for($i=0; $i<count($args); $i++) {
        $param_references[] = & $args[$i];
    }
    call_user_func_array(array(
        $sql,
        'bindParam'
    ), $param_references);
}
```

This is the usaqe :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Auth_tokens (username, password_hash, selector_hash, expiry_date) values (?, ?, ?,?)";  
insert($sql, 'param_types', array($username, $random_password_hash, $random_selector_hash, $expiry_date));
```

I tried to use `func_get_args();` in param but mixed it up totaly :(

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You function can be simplified to:

```
function insert($sql, $param_types, $args) {
    $stmt= $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($args);
}
```

As `execute` can use array of values as its argument. These values will be used in the query.

In this case `$param_types` argument is **useless**.

**Update**: still not clear what you expect, but code to start with is:

```
function insert($sql, $param_types, $args) {
    $stmt= $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $this->CreateParams($stmt, $param_types, $args);
    $stmt->execute();
}

function CreateParams($stmt, $param_types, $args) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($args as $argument) {
        $stmt->bindValue($i + 1, $argument, $param_types[$i]);
        $i++;
    }
}

// Calling as:

insert(
    'INSERT INTO Auth_tokens (username, password_hash, selector_hash, expiry_date) values (?, ?, ?, ?)', 
    [\PDO::PARAM_STR, \PDO::PARAM_STR, \PDO::PARAM_STR, \PDO::PARAM_STR], 
    [$username, $random_password_hash, $random_selector_hash, $expiry_date]
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as I mentioned in question I know how to use function with execute arrags. took 1 hour of Your Comon Sense time to explain me here :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58856805/how-to-call-a-function-multiple-times-with-where-clause-in-php-pdo I want to bind values and I created `$param_types` to get bind values. any suggestion how to use bindParams ?

Comment: And what's the point in complicating your code when you can use simple `execute($args)`?

Comment: Binding values not much safer on user managments inserting values on their types like STR, INT ETC ?

Comment: PDO will extract data type from values passed in `$args`

Comment: Well you are wrong on this account. PDO will never guess the data type as it could be dangerous. Instead, it will bind all parameters as strings.

Comment: @Dilek nope, is is not "much safer". There is no ground for such a statement. Binding all values as strings is as safe as any other method.

Comment: @YourCommonSense thanks your my hero, I need to wait for an acceptable answer then sorry u_mulder

Comment: Updated my answer with another snippet, where you can control your data types. @YourCommonSense thanks for remark about pdo data types.

Comment: @u_mulder Thanks I was trying it, and was about to ask you for calling part :) Thanks I can cover rest I think, and need to read bindParam vs BindValue Thanks again.

Comment: this new function doesn't support named parameters

Comment: @Dilek I would **definitely** keep just `execute($args)` without any `CreateParams()` which is useless, cumbersome and bloat your code for no reason.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I will keep that way just do some filters for inputs from users. and keep example from mulder in mind to use if needed in future with some changes, As my function in question was very close to work.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @dilek You can't delete this question, because it has been well received. There's no reason to delete it. If you have a different one you can ask, but make sure it is different than this one.